# dimension of subspace 8

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Let $W_1 ,W_2 ,W_3 $ be three distinct subspaces of $\mathbb R^{10}$such that each has dimension 9. $W=W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3 $.What will be dimension of W?
I think dimension of $W$ will be 7 since $W_1 ,W_2 ,W_3 $ are distinct.But answer is dimension of $W$ could be 8 as well.

According to my reasoning Let $\{a_1, a_2 ,...,a_{10}\}$ be elements of basis of $\mathbb R^{10}$ .Now we can choose basis for $W_1$ any nine elements, say  $\{a_1, a_2 ,...,a_{9}\}$.Now,for $W_2$ we choose $\{a_2 ,...,a_{10}\}$ as basis. To make $W$ of dimension 8 we $\{a_2 ,...,a_8,a_{9}\}$ must be in the basis of $W_3$.Now to complete $W_3$,only one dimension is needed for which we have two choices either $a_1$ or $a_{10}$.Choosing any of them will make $W_3$ either equal to $W_1$ or $W_2$. I could not find any any case where dimension of $W$ is 8. I don't understand what went wrong. Please help.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct until the end, but then you could choose a *linear combination* of $a_1$ and $a_{10}$, e.g. $w=a_1+a_{10}$. Observe $w\neq a_1$ and $w\neq a_{10}$, yet $w$ does not contribute to the dimension of $W$.

Comment: I think from the beginning we have problems with your argument: you seem to believe that given one basis of the whole space $\;\Bbb R^{10}\;$ we can choose from it basis for the subspaces, or if you don't believe this then you only are checking one single, very particular, case...

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand the OP is trying to determine if it is *possible* that the dimension of $W$ is 8, so yes, a particular case is enough...

Comment: I got your point.So what could be least dimension for W and how to prove that@DonAntonio

Answer (score 4):

Consider these subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$:

- $W_1=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,z=0\}$;
- $W_2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,x=0\}$;
- $W_3=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,x+z=0\}$.

They are distinct. However, $\dim(W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3)=1$, not $0$. The dimension is $1$ because $W_1\cap W_2\cap W_3=\{(0,y,0)\,|\,y\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: This was not meant to be a direct answer, but it is easy to build one from this idea. Take $W_1=\{(x_1,\dots,x_9,0)\in\mathbb{R}^{10}\}$, $W_2=\{(x_1,\dots,x_9,0,x_{10})\in\mathbb{R}^{10}\}$ and $W_3=\{(x_1,\dots,x_8,x_9,-x_9)\in\mathbb{R}^{10}\}$.

Comment: But in your example $W_1$ and $W_3$ are not distinct. @joseCarlosSantos

Comment: Since $(1,0,0)$ belongs to $W_1$ but not to $W_3$, I would say that, yes, they are distinct. Why do you disagree?

Comment: I was talking about the one you have mentioned in comments.But I was wrong with that, they are distinct.But then how can $W_2$ have 11 components@josecarlossantos

Comment: My mistake. It should have been $W_2=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_8,0,x_{10}\in\mathbb{R}^{10}\}$.

Comment: So,$W_1 \cap W_2$ is a subspace of $W_3$,which is of dimension 8.But It's strange that two subspace can have same dimension still one is contained in another. For example $W_1$ is contained in $W_3$ @josecarlossantos

Comment: Not quite. $\dim W_3=9$.

Comment: Dim W1is also 9 since each vector of W1has 9 independent component x1to x9 ,only one component is fixed. –@josecarlossantos